# Deserialize unpredictable JSON property as string

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a third-party API response with one very unpredictable property, the rest are OK.

Sometimes the property is a full nested object, sometimes it's a blank string, sometimes it is an array... The docs are not very good.

Here are some sample responses, but there could be more variations:

```
"errors": {
    "invalid_player_ids" : ["5fdc92b2-3b2a-11e5-ac13-8fdccfe4d986", "00cb73f8-5815-11e5-ba69-f75522da5528"]
  }

"errors": ["Notification content must not be null for any languages."]

"errors": ""
```

Luckily this property is not too important, but a nice-to-have for logging purposes.

Is it possible to deserialize the model as usual but for this particular property `errors`, deserialize the whole thing into a string property? Like so?

```
public string Errors { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the json you would receive, and the resulting data type (with values) you want in the end?

Comment: `public dynamic Error { get; set; }` might do it

Comment: I do not think dynamic is useful because I cannot predict structure, so I won't be able to read it. I would like to get a string of the object for that property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) to handle the unpredictable property.  It can handle any JSON, and if you need to log it out, you can just use `ToString()` to do it.

```
public class Response
{
    public JToken Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
Response resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
Console.WriteLine("Errors: " + resp.Errors.ToString());
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5jXHjV

Comment: Excellent, that did what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Like [@stuartd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382854/json-deserialize-single-property-as-string/55383973#comment97487810_55382854) has stated, a `dynamic` property also does the same thing.

#### dotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dVzsZm

#### Here's the working code.

I created a helper readonly property that returns `ToString` of the `dynamic` property. You could also do without it.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DynamicErrorsJson
{
    public class ApiResponse
    {
        public dynamic Errors { get; set; }

        public string ErrorsString
        {
            get
            {
                string value = string.Empty;
                if (Errors != null)
                {
                    value = Errors.ToString();
                }

                return value;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listErrorsJson = @"{ ""errors"": {""invalid_player_ids"" : [""5fdc92b2-3b2a-11e5-ac13-8fdccfe4d986"", ""00cb73f8-5815-11e5-ba69-f75522da5528""] } }";
            var stringErrorsJson = @"{ ""errors"": [""Notification content must not be null for any languages.""] }";
            var noErrorsJson = @"{""errors"": """" }";

            var listErrorsResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(listErrorsJson);
            var stringErrorsJsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(stringErrorsJson);
            var noErrorsJsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(noErrorsJson);

            Console.WriteLine("listErrorsJson Response: {0}\n\t", listErrorsResponse.ErrorsString);
            Console.WriteLine("stringErrorsJson Response: {0}\n\t", stringErrorsJsonResponse.ErrorsString);
            Console.WriteLine("noErrorsJson Response: {0}\n\t", noErrorsJsonResponse.ErrorsString);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit...");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Here's the output

[image]